# Delete Duplicates (same polycount) Maxscript

Tags: arrays, duplicates, maxscript

I want to remove all duplicate objects from a scene, I want to find the duplicates by comparing polycount of all objects.

When I've found the polycount of each object i want to group all objects with same polycount together and delete all but 1 of them. Should be simple, i am having trouble building an array with all duplicate objects in it though...

My code throws no errors but doesn't add any objects to #(duplicates) array. My code does determine polycount for all objects and puts it in objs_info array.

```
-- Remove object duplicates
clearselection()
select geometry
deselect helpers
objs = selection as array

objS_info = #()
objS_info2 = #()

dups = #()
for obj in objs do(

    obj_info = #()
    obj_dups = #()

    ConvertTo obj Editable_Poly
    PolyCount_src = polyop.getNumFaces obj
    --resetxform obj ; maxOps.CollapseNodeTo obj 1 true --reset Xform + collapse stack
    delta_x_src =  ((-1 * obj.min.x) + obj.max.x) 
    delta_z_src = ((-1 * obj.min.z) + obj.max.z)
    append obj_info PolyCount_src
    delta_ratio_src = delta_x_src/delta_z_src 
    for i in 1 to objs.count do(

        obj_dups = #()

        if objs[i] != obj do(
            ConvertTo obj Editable_Poly
            PolyCount = polyop.getNumFaces obj
            --resetxform obj ; maxOps.CollapseNodeTo obj 1 true --reset Xform + collapse stack
            delta_x =  ((-1 * obj.min.x) + obj.max.x) 
            delta_z = ((-1 * obj.min.z) + obj.max.z)
            delta_ratio = delta_x/delta_z 
            if(delta_ratio == delta_ratio_src and PolyCount == PolyCount_src) do(
                append obj_dups objs[i]
                )

            )
    )
append dups obj_dups
)

format "dups = % \n " obj_dups
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to skin a cat. Note that testing floats for equality (what you do when comparing the bounding box size ratios is rather risky (see for example [comparing float values](http://creativescratchpad.blogspot.com/2013/01/maxscript-float-comparison.html) if you want to keep that check). Grouping by the size can be done for example like this:

```
objsByNumFaces = for obj in geometry where canConvertTo obj mesh collect
(
    local snapshot = snapshotAsMesh obj
    local data = dataPair obj:obj numFaces:snapshot.numFaces
    delete snapshot
    data
)

qsort objsByNumFaces (fn _ x y = x.numFaces - y.numFaces)

counter = 0
prevCount = -1
objsPartitioned = #()

for pair in objsByNumFaces do
(
    if pair.numFaces == prevCount then
        append objsPartitioned[objsPartitioned.count] pair.obj
    else
    (
        prevCount = pair.numFaces
        append objsPartitioned #(pair.obj)
    )
)
```

The `objsPartitioned` array will then contain objects grouped by number of faces.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I agree that comparing floats is quite risky (I did not think about it before reading your answer). Comparing vertex count would be a better option (since vertex count is an integer value), will try and modify your script to also compare vertex count of objs.

Comment: I've managed to modify the script in such a way that it checks if both polycount and vertcount are equal :)